# How to display index translation (rails-i18n) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, indexing, message, rails-i18n

Rails 5 adds error indexing using (indexing of errors on nested attributes) for models:

```
class Order
    has_many :operations, index_errors: true

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :operations
end
```

```
class Operation
    has_many :inv_items, index_errors: true

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :inv_items
end
```

As a result of calling order.errors.full_messages
I get errors in this form:

*{:"operations[0].inv_items[0].serial_num"=>["Can't be empty"], :"operations[0].inv_items[1].serial_num"=>["Can't be empty"]}*

In file .yml i can directly set the translation

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      warehouse/order/operations[0]/inv_items[0]:
        serial_num: 'Serial number'
```

But how to organize a translation without indicating each index?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem here. Did you find any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the translation for the Model without nesting it within its associations. Something like the snippet below.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      inv_item: Inventory Item
    attributes:
      inv_item:
        serial_num: Serial Number
```

[Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)